# How do I set SharePoint O365 Versioning Settings so "Only the users who can approve items (and the author of the item)" works?

Tags: office-365, versioning, settings

I have a Form Library in O365 where I need to allow all site users to add an item, but they should only be able to see their own items, not other users items.  I set versioning so the "Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)" is selected.  And I created a special permission group for all users that doesn't allow them to approve items.  But all users can still see all items.  Is this a bug in O365?  I was able to get this to work in SP WSS 3.0, and I copied all of the settings from that version, but I can't get this to work.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think OOTB it is not possible.

You will need to give item level permission or Create Separate view and filter that view by "Created By = [Me]".

Comment: How is it not possible OOTB? There's a setting for it.

Comment: Have you done changes in "Who should see draft items in this document library?" section?